# AJAX Live Search- Send Multiple Values to PHP

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

HTML CODE

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">

<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search2" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
```

SCRIPT

```
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("Hint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("Hint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?value=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

This code works fine for single `<input>`. But, I need to pass two inputs values to JavaScript function and send two values to `gethint.php` like:

```
function showHint(str,str1) 
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("Hint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?value=" + str+ "&ids=" +str1, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I tried like this but I could not solve it.

Comment: So what is the specific problem with second approach?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `id` attribute to your textfields, and just call `showHint()`. Then, in your JavaScript function, get the value of theses textfields:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" 
       placeholder="Search1" id="search1" onkeyup="showHint()">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" 
       placeholder="Search2" id="search2" onkeyup="showHint()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function showHint() {
    var str1 = document.querySelector('#search1').value;
    var str2 = document.querySelector('#search2').value;

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("Hint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?value=" + encodeURIComponent(str1) + "&ids=" + encodeURIComponent(str2), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Note that you could use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly encode the strings to be used in URL.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the value form the input fields in the function instead of passing them to it. For this you should add IDs to the input fields:

```js
function showHint(str, str1) {
  // if no values are passed, get the data from the elements
  if (!str) str = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  if (!str1) str1 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("Hint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      } else {console.log(this.status);}
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?value=" + str+ "&ids=" +str1, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search1" onkeyup="showHint()">
    
<input id="input2" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search2" onkeyup="showHint()">
```

With this you could still invoke the function with custom strings